# Modifing the return value of reduce() expression modifies the input

Tags: python

I wrote a function to collect all values into a single list from a dictionary where each value is a list. However, when I later modified that list, I found that my original dictionary was modified too!

```
from functools import reduce 

d = {'foo': [1,2,3]}
all_vals = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, d.values())
all_vals.append(4)
print(d)
# {'foo': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

This doesn't happen if the dictionary has multiple key/values though:

```
from functools import reduce 

d = {'foo': [1,2,3], 'bar': [9]}
all_vals = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, d.values())
all_vals.append(4)
print(d)
# {'foo': [1, 2, 3], 'bar': [9]}
```

The dictionary now stays unmodified. Can anybody explain why python has this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, `.values()` has a single value, `reduce` simply returns that list. When you modify it with `.append`, you are *modifying the same list*.

In the second case, the function actually runs, so `x + y` produces *a new list*.

As an aside, you shouldn't be using this algorithm to flatten values. It is unnecessarily inefficient (quadratic time) when a simple:

```
vals = [v for values in d.values() for v in values]
```

Is linear time.

Answer (score 3):

Because in the first case your `all_vals` is simply `d.values()[0]` because the reduce lambda is never called because there are no two elements to reduce with each other.

In the second case you do have two elements which are combined to form a new list which no longer references the list originally in the dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Reducing an iterable of a single element never applies the reduction function, since that would require two elements. In this case the initial element is returned directly.

```
>>> a = [0, 1, 2]
>>> a is reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [a])
True
```

As a result, all modifications to the result of `reduce` are visible on its input element and vice versa, since the two are the same objects.

One can avoid this with an *initializer* so that the reduction function can be applied even to a single element iterable or by manually applying an initial reduction:

```
>>> a = [0, 1, 2]
>>> # this accepts empty iterables
>>> a is reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [a], [])
False
>>> # this rejects empty iterables
>>> a is reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [a]) + []
False
```

---

This behaviour is guaranteed by the language specification:

> ### [functools.reduce(function, iterable[, initializer])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce)
>
> […] If *initializer* is not given and *iterable* contains only one item, the first item is returned.

Comment: If anyone interested in implementation, [this is where it's happening](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_functoolsmodule.c#L693-L701)